# Are duplicate questions good in some cases?

Tags: discussion

[What happens with microtransactions if 1 IOTA = 1$](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/565/what-happens-with-microtransactions-if-1-iota-1)

[Does IOTA become less accessible the further its value increases?](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/486/does-iota-become-less-accessible-the-further-its-value-increases)

These questions answer the exact same thing.
But the questions are phrased differently and if people want to find an answer to their question they may search either wording. If only one question exists and they try the other wording they may not find an answer.

Should the duplicate question get closed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When duplicate questions are closed, they are **not** deleted. This is a deliberate feature—by closing duplicates but leaving them to remain on the site:

- There is only one canonical question where all the answers are posted, but...
- Users coming in from Google will still find the duplicate question if they search for that wording.

If a duplicate question has answers, they still remain on the duplicate, and a link to the open master question is placed in a banner. If the duplicate is closed before being answered, users coming in from Google will [automatically be redirected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125220/336144) to the answered master question.

In answer to your question: **yes, the duplicate should be closed**, because it will still stay on the site as a 'signpost' for other users searching for an answer, but having only one canonical question prevents good answers being spread among many duplicates.